# Custom Http Listener in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, http, httplistener

The .NET has a built in HttpListener class, however I was wondering how I could roll my own Http Listener. I know there are a lot of implications to this, but I just want see the browser and my own app interact with each other.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
Socket servSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
servSocket.ExclusiveAddressUse = false; // Does this matter?
servSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
servSocket.Listen(10);

byte[] buffer;

do
{
    try
    {
        Socket clientSocket = servSocket.Accept();

        Console.WriteLine("Received Request at: {0}.", DateTime.Now);

        EndPoint remoteEP = clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint;
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        clientSocket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, SocketFlags.None, ref remoteEP);
        string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(request);
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><head><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:;base64,=\"></head><body></body></html>");
        clientSocket.Send(buffer);

        clientSocket.Close();
        clientSocket.Dispose();
    }
    catch { }
}
while (this.isRunning);
```

This sort of works, however two issues I have noted, is that the `clientSocket` local end-point is on the same port as the `servSocket`. With the built-in HttpListener, the request gets handled by a random local end-point port. How can I mimic this?

I have set the `ExclusiveAddressUse` flag to false, however I still cannot bind more than one socket to that particular end-point, so what is its exact use?

Furthermore, from time to time I get a SocketException with 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'. What could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is "you don't really care about that".

TCP works by estabilishing a two-way "virtual" persistent connection. To achieve this illusion, it uses a separate port for communication with a given client. You still connect to port 80 (for example), but a thousand clients use a thousand different ports for the actual communication with the server.

`ExclusiveAddressUse` allows you to bind more sockets to the same port - but each has to have its own IP address.

Networking is hard. Us as high an abstraction as you can, be it TcpListener, HttpListener or even OWIN.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning OWIN. It was interesting! So I'm not sure I got this right, let me see:

1. Client connects to server on port 80.
2. Server receives request, passes it on to some other module, terminates connection on port 80, and starts listening for new connections.
3. The other module finishes processing and sends request to end-client IP:port from a new random port on the server.

Is this correct?

Comment: @ZuiqPazu Simplified, but yeah, that's more or less the case. Do note that this is part of the TCP driver itself. In practice, you do care about those random ports (called "ephemeral ports"), since there's a limited amount of those. However, unless you have a lot of concurrent connections and people connecting and disconnecting all the time, you should be fine. The defaults are rather low on desktop machines, though. In any case, it does mean that however performant your app is, one network interface can at most maintain 65534 TCP connections at once (in practice, much less).

Comment: @ZuiqPazu The thing is, TCP is the protocol that gives you the "session" and "connection" illusion. So there's no "termination" of the connection on port 80 - there never was a "connection" in the first place. The underlying IP protocol doesn't care, for example. The same process (nor its limits) doesn't apply to UDP, for example. You might want to install a tool like WireShark to monitor what network communication actually looks like, if you want to dig deeper into this. For example, the TCP connection init means 1. SYN C->S, 2. SYN ACK S->C, 3. ACK C->S; 2 roundtrips before any data is sent.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed response :) I'm very glad. I will accept your answer as the solution.